# Data-structures used in MySQL, Oracle, MS Access and DB2

Tags: data-structures

I'm looking to distinguish between **datastructures** used in **MySQL, Oracle, MS Access** and **DB2** Database Management Systems.

There are some information on them independently. But Direct comparison can't be found on datastructures used. What are the datastructures used in them and how they make them strong or week?